# Extra zeros in OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Tried building 'cv::Mat' from 2D array but I find that extra zeros are added to the Mat which I am not able to understand. The code I tried is :

```
int a2D [7][7];
for(loop condition)
{
   a2D[x][y] = value;
   cout << "Value :"<< value << endl;
}
Mat outmat = Mat(7, 7, CV_8UC1, &a2D);
cout << "Mat2D : "<< outmat  << endl;
```

Output is :

```
Value : 22
Value : 179
Value : 145
Value : 170
Value : 251
Value : 250
Value : 171
Value : 134
Value : 218
Value : 178
Value : 6
....Upto 49 values.
Mat2D : [ 22,   0,   0,   0, 179,   0,   0;
   0, 145,   0,   0,   0, 170,   0;
   0,   0, 251,   0,   0,   0, 250;
   0,   0,   0, 171,   0,   0,   0;
 134,   0,   0,   0, 218,   0,   0;
   0, 178,   0,   0,   0,   6,   0;
   0,   0,  72,   0,   0,   0,  25]
```

As in Mat2D output after every value 3 zeros are added.Why and how?

Comment: You're taking 4 input values for Mat. You should go check how values are assigned when Mat is initialized--most likely default values.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `int` buffer to initialize `cv::Mat` with `unsigned char` elements, that explains why values are written at each fourth element (`int` seems to be 4 times larger than `unsigned char` on your machine).

Changing type of `a2D` to `unsigned char` should fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Just changed the 'int' to 'unsigned char' and it worked like a magic!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can accept the answer to help others having the same problem identify the solution quicker.

Comment: Actually, after you have edited the question, I am not sure your code will work fine. You'd better leave the 1-dimensional array in place, and just fix the indexing, like `a2D[y*7 + x] = value;`

Comment: 2D array worked in my example. And I think a2D, &a2D, *a2D, a2D[0], &a2D[0], and &a2D[0][0] point to base of array. Any of the representation could be chosen to construct the 'cv::Mat'.

Comment: That is true, but i was not sure that `int a2D [7][7];` guarantees that the data will be laid out contiguously in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `a2D[x][y] = value` is wrong if the type of `a2D` is `int[49]`, you are writing outside the array. The 0's you see are uninitialized garbage.

You have to access `a2D` with a single index. For example: `a2D[i] = value`.

Comment: I guess it was just a kind of pseudo-code to demonstrate the setup, because `for(loop condition)` wouldn't have compiled either

Comment: Corrected the typo!! Sry